# Check if cookie saving / disable it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a Google Chrome extension that allows you to manage cookies:

For example in Facebook when you log in, this extension would say "Do you wanna save the cookie? Yes / No"

I use javascript, I have the following code in it but It doesn't work for me.

```
if(!document.__defineGetter__) {
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
        get: function(){return ''},
        set: function(){return true},
    });
} else {
    document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function() { return '';} );
    document.__defineSetter__("cookie", function() {} );
}
```

Can someone  help me wich way can I check If cookie going to save and disable it if user select "don't save cookie" option?

Comment: That will not affect cookies sent by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the [`chrome.cookies` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).

Specifically, you can hook up to [`chrome.cookies.onChanged` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged) and react accordingly to every cookie added.

There is also an API to simply disable cookies, possibly per domain: [`chrome.contentSettings` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings).

---

The usual applies: if you're new to Chrome extensions, read through the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Also see the [Samples page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:cookies).